# How to click on html element only once?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have a list of elements, when I click on the element, I want to add textNode to the Array, with only one click on the element. I don't need the duplicates values in the array. Then I want to stop pressed when I have 5 elements in the array

What I tried didn't work!

```
  <div>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
    <span>10</span>
  </div>
```

```
    let numArr = [];
    let elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('span')];

    elements.forEach((item) => {
      item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
         item.classList.add('green');
         numArr.push(item.textContent);
         if(numsArr.length === 5) {
            item.setAttribute('disabled', true);
         } else {
            item.setAttribute('disabled', true);
         }
    })
    });
```

I expect the output of `[2, 5, 7, 10, 3]` Any values of pressed items without duplicates in array!

Comment: Just remove the listener in the handler

Answer (score 2):

Just check if the element text is already in `array` before add a new item
in code below i used `indexOf` to do that:

```
    elements.forEach((item) => {
          item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
             item.classList.add('green');
             let text = item.textContent;
             if(numArr.indexOf(text) == -1){
                numArr.push(item.textContent);
             }
             if(numArr.length === 5) {
                item.setAttribute('disabled', true);
             } else {
                item.setAttribute('disabled', true);
             }
        })
```

Comment: @Amessihel Done !  :)